# Enumerating all available change journal records

Tags: winapi, file-io, ntfs, watch, deviceiocontrol

I have a problem with enumerating change journal records.

```
//my params    
READ_USN_JOURNAL_DATA read_journal_data;
read_journal_data.StartUsn = ... //next USN
read_journal_data.ReasonMask = 0xFFFFFFFF;
read_journal_data.ReturnOnlyOnClose = FALSE;
read_journal_data.UsnJournalID = ... //ID of current journal
read_journal_data.BytesToWaitFor = 9000;
read_journal_data.Timeout = 5; //5 seconds

BOOL result = DeviceIoControl(this->volume_handle_, FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL,
         &read_journal_data, sizeof(read_journal_data), this->change_journal_data_buffer_,
         this->change_journal_data_buffer_, &this->valid_bytes_in_buffer_, NULL);
```

As you see, `Timeout` is nonzero and `BytesToWaitFor` is nonzero too.
I understood that when `FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL` call reaches the end of the change journal, it must wait `Timeout` seconds and then return all (0 or more)
available records within the range of `BytesToWaitFor`. However, for some reason I am watching completely different behavior: `DeviceIoControl` with `FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL` and other listed parameters can take for several minutes - until some NEW changes have been occured in file system.
Why `READ_USN_JOURNAL_DATA.Timeout` does not limit duration of `FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL` request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It behaves exactly how it suppose to behave, to be specific:

> In either case, after the time-out period any new data appended to the change journal is processed. If there are still no records to return from the specified set, the time-out period is repeated. In this mode, FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL remains outstanding until at least one record is returned or I/O is canceled.

See [MSDN, section Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks... I simply misunderstood the purpose of these parameters. Additional information can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0999/journal/journal.aspx) (Timeout and BytesToWaitFor)

Comment: Yes, this is good introduction to NTFS journals. Anyway, quite comprehensive source of information about NTFS journals is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363798.aspx